# Can't save changes to my settings.py file in django

Tags: python, django

Whenever I make any changes in `settings.py` file, and try to save it , I get an alert saying

```
UNABLE TO SAVE: PERMISSION DENIED
```

First I thought it is because I am not the owner of the folder, but after changing settings and gaining ownership I am still getting the same alert.

[image]

Comment: Problem is only for settings.py or error is for views.py, urls.py and models.py alsp?

Answer (score 0):

Double check permissions for all the files under each directory starting at /. Just a thought.
or Try moving folder to a different location